# Vimeo AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, vimeo

I am trying to get the AJAX response from Vimeo, to extract a thumbnail without JQuery.
But I am not receiving the response, although if I type the response query (http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/30408418.json) in to the browser, I am offered to download file and it contains the response data in json format...
I have just tried copying the same request into a page where I had the Flickr responses working (with jQuery), and the response is still empty, so I think that this is not a JSONP issue.

heres my code

```
var vimeoVid= {};
var request = getHTTPObject();
if(request){
    var requString="http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/30408418.json";
    request.open('GET',requString,true);
    request.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(request.readyState==4){
        vimeoVid = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.send();
    }
    else
    {
    alert('Sorry, your browser doen\'t support XMLHttpRequest');
    }
    console.log("vimeoVid");
```

where

```
function getHTTPObject(){
if(typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined")

XMLHttpRequest=function(){
try{return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHHTP.6.0");}
catch(e){}

try{return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");}
catch(e){}
try{return new ActiveXObject
("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
catch(e){}
return false;
}
return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AJAX doesn't work cross-domain (except for modern browsers and where specifically allowed). You *have* to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Example URL: http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/30408418.json?callback=bacon

Comment: Thanks, That's what I thought it was at first, but then I tried it in the latest Firefox, which, according to MDN supports cross domain requests, and tried the same string in a script I wrote earlier with jQuery, where originally I was getting data off of flickr and jQuery was handling JSONP, it didn't work either.
I didn't specify callback in both cases, does this matter?

Comment: It *supports* cross-domain requests, but they must be allowed by the origin. The server must send an "Access-Control" header, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin. The example URL I gave should work fine with `jQuery.getJSON`.